# Find unmatched between 2 tables using field as selection criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following tables as a example.

**Table 1**

| EmpID | LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | John |
| 2 | Jones | Bob |
| 3 | Citizen | Jane |

**Table 2**

| EmpID | ReqID | ReqDesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Car |
| 1 | 2 | Diploma |
| 1 | 3 | Phone |
| 2 | 1 | Car |
| 2 | 3 | Phone |
| 3 | 1 | Car |
| 3 | 2 | Diploma |
| 3 | 3 | Phone |

I want to return all records from Table 1 that don't have an entry in Table 2 that don't have a Diploma for example so ReqID = 2

This query gives me all records back though not just Bob Jones' record. As they have other records that ReqID <> 2. Is there some way to group them to achieve this?

```
SELECT Table1.EMPID,
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.EMPID = Table2.EMPID
WHERE Table2.ReqID <> 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.EmpID
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.EMPID = Table1.EmpID AND Table2.ReqID = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
SELECT t1.*,
  FROM Table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (select 1 from Table2 t2 
        where t1.EMPID = T2.EMPID and t2.reqdesc = 'Diploma');
```

Comment: This will return the rows where there IS a value for Diploma, the OP wants where there is NO value

Comment: @MartinCairney Please read it carefully - `I want to return all records from Table 1 that don't have an entry in Table 2 that don't have a Diploma`

Comment: OP comments that ONLY Bob Jones' record should come back. His is the only one that doesn't have a Diploma entry - hence a NOT EXISTS.  The double negative in that sentence does make it unclear though

Comment: Let OP come back with his comment. That can be achieved using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `EXISTS`

Comment: The above query returns the records that have a match for 'Diploma' in table 2. Changing the `EXISTS` to `NOT EXISTS` returns the correct data where all records without 'Diploma' are returned.